# How to run elastic service in gitlab runner?

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hi stack overflow community!
 I'm new to gitlab-ci runner and and here's a part of my gitlab-ci config file. 
...

```
  - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.3
    alias: elasticsearch
    command: [ "bin/elasticsearch", "-Ediscovery.type=single-node" ]
```

...

This is the configurations in my gitlab-ci runner file. But this is not working. None of my elastic search based queries are working.

Please let me know if I'm missing something or if this is a known issue?

Comment: can you share the entire yml of the stage?

Comment: thanks for your response @Amityo , let me add a little more context here. The error is because of memory settings. I've tried the following ::::     ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms3g -Xmx3g"                and sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Comment: it will really help if you can edit the question with the entire yaml of the current stage (right now it is lacking in information and hard to understand the full picture) + if you can add the error/log from your build when trying to connect to elasticsearch